# How to modify querystring using URL rewriting?

Tags: iis, rewrite, querystring, isapi-rewrite

I am having very less knowledge in URL rewriting, So not sure weather this can be done or not using URL rewrite?

I have a URL like
**www.test.com/categroy.cfm?categoryid=12&weight=any&brandid=23**

For weight parameter: if its value is 'any' i want to remove it from the url .

For brandid parameter: if brandid is 'any' remove it else replace with 'filter_brand=value'

Outpul like: **www.test.com/categroy.cfm?categoryid=12&filter_brand=23**

Is it possible ? If yes could anyone please show me an example. I am using IIS.

Comment: What are you using? IIS Rewriting? or ISAPI_Rewrite?

Comment: @Andrew: iiS rewriting.

Answer (score -1):

Goolge iis rewrite query string

See the fourth result.

[IIS URL Rewrite Module Query String Parameters](https://serverfault.com/questions/372991/iis-url-rewrite-module-query-string-parameters)