# IIS 7 URL Rewrite Only If No File Nor Subdirectory Nor Query String

Tags: iis-7, redirect, rewrite, regex, url

(I posted [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786561/iis-7-url-rewrite-only-if-no-file-nor-subdirectory-nor-query-string) because searches for an answer showed related questions on StackOverflow, which got answers and many upvotes. But my question so far earned a downvote and an "off-topic" close vote, so I'm trying asking here where it may be considered more on-topic.)

I would like to do a URL rewrite (or redirecton if need be, like [in this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018818/iis7-url-redirection-from-root-to-sub-directory)), except I would like it only to rewrite/redirect if the requested URL is only the site root (with no files or subdirectories and no query strings).

i.e. I want only requests for **TheSite.net** to rewrite/redirect to **TheSite.net/home.htm**, but requests for **TheSite.net/FAQ.htm** or **TheSite.net/sub** or **TheSite.net/?parameter=yep** to not be rewritten/redirected.

I have gotten rewrites and redirects to work such as:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Rewrite home page to Home.htm" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/Home.htm" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also tried `<match url="^$" />` and `<match url="TheSite.net" />`, but those naturally rewrite TheSite.net/?parameter=yep too, and I need it to not do that. Perhaps if there is another attribute of `<match>` which lets me match empty query string but not if there is a query string (or not match if there is anything is after the slash)?

I'm hoping an appropriate rule could do what I wanted, but my RegEx syntax skills are not up to the task and I haven't found an example of something close enough.

On this site, I see [IIS URL Rewrite Module Query String Parameters](https://serverfault.com/questions/372991/iis-url-rewrite-module-query-string-parameters) looks like it might be the sort of thing that could work, though what I want is the opposite - to only rewrite if there is no query string or other content after the domain name in the URL.

Comment: Have you tried using an empty string in the match URL?

Comment: @JimL. I had not tried that, so I did try it just now. The result was a 500 server error message for all URLs.

Comment: As in `match url=""`?  Well, another way of specifying an empty URL might be "^$".  Similarly a trivial URL of "^/$" might also work.

Comment: @JimL. Yes, match url="" gives the 500 error. ^ and ^$ match every page. I need to not rewrite links to URLs with query strings, files or subdirectories after the domain name. ?/$ matches nothing, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, subject to complete testing of weird cases, I seem to have found a solution via playing with Conditions, i.e.:

```
<rule name="Rewrite home page to Home.htm" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+=(.+)" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/Home.htm" />
</rule>
```